# How to remove button through alert dialog inside ListView adapter

Tags: android

I have a delivery app in which I am using list view , this is my [layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8yOh.jpg) (behind the buttons the textview are hidden) , When buttons are pressed I make request to my server through async task and if successful I remove the button and just show the text behind,this works in `picked up` option where I have no alert dialog but when delivery button is pressed I want to show alert dialog prompting to enter otp and then make request , this works but  this time the `delivery` button is not getting removed and the hidden text is not shown and it just restores the orignal state of the adapter  if successfull , any suggestion would be great , this is my adapter `getView()`

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, null);



   final TextView oid = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.orderid);
    final Button pickedup=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button);
    final Button delievered=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button4);
    TextView res = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.resname);
    final TextView hidden = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    final TextView hidden2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    TextView user=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.user);
    ImageView resphone=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.resphn);
    ImageView userphone=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.userphn);
    final TextView useradd=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.useradd);
    final TextView resadd=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.Resadd);
    String check=productlist.get(position).getPicklog();
    if(Integer.parseInt(check)==2) {
        pickedup.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        hidden.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
    else{
        delievered.setEnabled(false);
    }


  
    oid.setText(productlist.get(position).getOrderId());
    res.setText(productlist.get(position).getRestaurant());
    user.setText(productlist.get(position).getUser());
    useradd.setText(productlist.get(position).getUseradd());
    resadd.setText(productlist.get(position).getResaddress());

    oid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            Intent  intent=new Intent(getContext(),Reciept.class);
           
            intent.putExtra("hello",showitem);
            getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    pickedup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          

           id=productlist.get(position).getOrderId();
           new pickup(pickedup,hidden,delievered).execute();
          // this is similar to delivery but this works and the button is removed from view

        }
    });

    delievered.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // creating new product in background thread

            id=productlist.get(position).getOrderId();

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

            

            
            View customView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.otp, null);
            
            final EditText otp=(EditText) customView.findViewById(R.id.editText) ;

            Button ok = (Button) customView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
            Button cancel = (Button) customView.findViewById(R.id.button4);
            builder.setView(customView);
            testDialog=builder.create();
            testDialog.show();


            ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                   
                    new deliever(delievered,hidden2,otp.getText().toString()).execute();


                }
            });
            cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    testDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });



        }
    });

    
    return v;

}
```

In my async request I declare a class like this

```
class deliever extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>

    {
        Button ab;
        TextView s;
        String otp;

        public deliever(Button delievered, TextView hidden2,String o) {
            ab=delievered;
            s=hidden2;
            otp=o;
        }
```

And if successful:

```
ab.setVisibility(View.GONE);//does'nt work
                        s.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//does'nt work
                        testDialog.dismiss();
```